# What does "two-plus-SO to splash" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bourne-legacy

In *The Bourne Legacy* (2012), Byer decides to eliminate all Outcome assets. He orders new meds distributed to the agents. He learns that both Numbers Three and Five are at the same location, and dispatches a U-CAV drone aircraft to kill both agents but only Number 5 evade the attack. Below is the transcript of controller of U-CAV drone aircraft on a radio scanner:

> Spec: Requesting fuel graph, say your state.
>
> PILOT: State **two-plus-SO to splash**.
>
> Spec: Copy, Solo. Fuel to bingo is green.

What does "two-plus-SO to splash" mean?

Comment: @Tetsujin I think it's fine as is, although this is a typo error as you state the basic question is asking for clarification of actual jargon.

Comment: More suited to https://aviation.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tetsujin Is clarification of verbal flubs in the dialog on topic here? If so, then clarification of typos in subtitles should also be on topic, because for people who are hard of hearing, the captioning *is* the dialog.

Comment: Just a note that Bingo is an indication that there is just enough fuel left to get back to base.

Comment: @R.M. - it's a typo in some unofficial version of the subs. I just checked the original, it's correct "two-plus-30 to splash"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In pilot jargon (possibly military only?) 'state' refers to asking for their fuel status.  It is usually responded in terms of number of hours plus minutes until 'splash', i.e. when they will run out of fuel.

So:

> State one plus two zero to splash

Means one hour twenty minutes of fuel remaining.

According to this [copy of the script](https://subslikescript.com/movie/The_Bourne_Legacy-1194173) the pilot is actually saying

> State two-plus-30 to splash

The 'fuel to bingo is green' indicates that they have enough fuel for a safe return to base.

Comment: According to [the script](https://subslikescript.com/movie/The_Bourne_Legacy-1194173), it's ***State two-pIus-30 to spIash***.

Comment: Can you actually hear the guy saying this line in the film?  Because while **SO** and **30** might *look* similar when written, they'd sound nothing alike at all.

Comment: Nice answer. Just to add, “Bingo” would be the calculated point in the route where the aircraft would have just enough fuel to return to the predetermined friendly base of safe landing plus reserve (Just in case) fuel. Reaching this point would necessitate discontinuing the mission and an immediate return to base.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman ... I only have copies of the script.  SO could be a mistake made in creating subtitles or it could be a mistake in transcribing the speech .. perhaps 'zero' to 'ess-o'.  It seems from research that this 'number+number" for hours and minutes is fairly standard, so it seems safe that this is not likely to be SO.